# Generic primitive type with casting

Tags: java, generics, casting

I've got a problem with my Java code. I want to make my method universal with using of generics types. It's easier to explain it with code:

```
public interface Destroyable {

    void destroy();

    default void destroyArray(byte[] array) {
        Arrays.fill(array, (byte)0);
    }

    default void destroyArray(char[] array) {
        Arrays.fill(array, (char)0);
    }

}
```

The point is, that I want my default method destroyArray to work with any type, like this:

```
public interface Destroyable {

    void destroy();

    default <E> void destroyArray(Class<E>[] array) {
        Arrays.fill(array, (E)0);
    }

}
```

It gives me error:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'int' to 'E'

Is there any simple solution to achieve this?

Comment: replace `0` with `null`. Also `Class<E>[]` should probably just be `E[]`

Comment: @Lino Wow, as simple as that, thank you :) One more question, is there any reason to keep it as `Class<E>[]` or just use `E[]` ?

Comment: It means something completely different. `Class<E>` is a `Class` object, a wrapper that provides reflection access to analyze contents of the class. Like getting names of methods and stuff like that. Whereas `E` is the class itself. So `Person` is a person class and `Class<Person>` is like a class which knows stuff about the `Person` class, like its method names.

Comment: Also another thing: `destroyArray()` should not be an instance method, but rather a `static` one, as it is just a helper

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Default value of objects

The problem with your code:

```
default <E> void destroyArray(E[] array) {
    Arrays.fill(array, (E) 0);
}
```

is that a general `E` type is of course not necessarily an `int` (or something that can be autoboxed like `Integer`). But you want to actually write some *default* value. Therefore you would need to create valid instances of `E`. Which, in general, is hard because you don't know anything about the type, including its constructors.

However, there is one valid value for all `Object`s, namely `null`. It indicates that there simply is no instance at the moment.

So the following would work for arbitrary types `E`:

```
default <E> void destroyArray(E[] array) {
    Arrays.fill(array, null);
}
```

---

### Primitives

However, with that you are still not able to fill primitive-type arrays like `int[]` since `E` can only be used for `Object`s, not primitives. You would need to hard-code additional methods for each primitive:

```
default void destroyArray(int[] array) {
    Arrays.fill(array, 0);
}

default void destroyArray(double[] array) {
    Arrays.fill(array, 0.0);
}

// ...
```

---

### Note on `Class<E>`

Your original code had `Class<E>[]` instead of `E[]`. Note that `Class<E>` means something completely different than `E[]`.

`Class<E>` is a `Class` object, a wrapper that provides Reflection-API access to **analyze contents of the class**. Like getting names of methods and stuff like that. Whereas `E` is the class itself.

So `Person` would be a `Person` class and `Class<Person>` is like a class which knows stuff about the `Person` class, like its method names.

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) of `Class` for more details.

Comment: "Whereas `E` is *an instance* of the class". Would probably be better

Comment: May bad, I just wanted to say thanks for your comment and upvote here ... and I already have at some point ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
default <E> void destroyArray(E[] array) {
    Arrays.fill(array, null);
}
```

The above might be what you intended. *However*, this wouldn't work with primitive types. Because primitive types are not allowed to be passed as generic type parameters, you will still need a `destroyByteArray`, `destroyIntArray` etc.

Also, `destroyArray` doesn't seem to belong in `Destroyable`. Shouldn't it just be in a helper class full of static methods? If I were you I would move it to there. It does not even call the `destroy` method, so it has no reason to be in `Destroyable`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Moving `destroyArray` outside `Destroyable` interface is definitelly good idea, since while I keep it, then every class that implements this interface, has no needed default methods from `Destroyable` interface and as you said, they are indenpendent of destroy method

Answer (score 3):

Your original approach with many overloaded methods is fine.

For primitive types, the generics would work for their **arrays** as:

```
default <A> void destroyArray(A array) {
    Class<?> arrayType = array.getClass();
    if (!arrayType.isArray()) {
        return;
    }
    Class<?> type = arrayType.getComponentType();
    if (type == int.class) {
        Arrays.fill((int[])array, 0);
    } else if (type == char.class) {
        Arrays.fill((char[])array, '\0');
    }
    //...
}
```

As you can see: this is hardly more compact, slower and less type safe, and secure forgotten primitive types.